# Posicionamento de Imagem em Lawtex

Tags: lawtex

Vou incluir um QR CODE em um template de petição. É possível colocar a imagem do QR code identada à esquerda ou à direita do template? Tentei usar como último parâmetro do `attach "right"` mas não deu certo:

`attach("QRCODE.png", "" , "" ,"20%" , "20%" , "right")`